# Creating my own crypto

Tags: cryptocurrency

Imagine this

1. I create my own defi cryptocurrency
2. I take out loans denominated in the currency, ie, legal contracts to give people money in the future
3. Then, I print more money for myself to inflate away the value of these liabilities.

Is this fraud? If I create a currency solely to take out loans which I later devalue isnt that fraud?

And this is what people actually do so its  not hypothetical. What about breach of fiduciary trust?

Comment: What does "defi" mean?  A search suggests it stands for "decentralized finance" - is this different than a normal cryptocurrency?

Comment: Also this likely depends on what the loan contract says.

Comment: Loan doesnt mention. I doubt anyone would agree to a loan where this was stated.

Comment: Defi doesnt matter

Comment: You are expecting what, someone to give you real cash (dollars, euros etc) in return for a currency you just created, and expect to pay them back through inflating the available currency you just created?

Comment: That is what people do. Is it legal?

Comment: @John https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2020/06/18/crypto-founder-admits-25-million-ico-backed-by-celebrities-was-a-scam/ yes its probably fraud and a bunch of other things, and many cryptocurrency issuers have fallen foul of the SEC and other regulatory bodies.  That said, your first issue is getting people to buy your currency with real money on the pretence that they get more later on with no guarantees of actual returns - the ridiculousness involved in that thinking may simply save you from actually breaking the law.

Comment: So basically the entire fiancne system is fraud and always has been because the fed prints money.

Comment: @Moo if there are no false statements or is probably legal; of course if the OP promises that "I have an agreement so you can use the currency in amazon" or that "there will be a controlled supply of currency to avoid inflation" knowing that they are false it could be illegal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a troll. Close & delete.

Comment: FYI: reducing debt through inflation is one the benefits of being a government https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/52952/18373 (as long as you emit your own currency, and the debt is in that currency.) I don't know of anyone having successfully sued a government on that basis. THAT would be a good question for you to ask, since it's probably what you wanted to ask in the first place. Also, a/the government can (legally) tax. If you try to do the same, it's called a racketeering.

Comment: Since the advent of legislated [central bank mandates](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/why-are-the-feds-goals-often-described-as-the-dual-mandate-and-not-the-tripl), e.g. to keep inflation low (but not zero), presumably nobody can claim the policy/mandate isn't known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I create a currency solely to take out loans which I later devalue isnt that fraud?

That scenario presents most of the *prima facie* elements of *fraud*. However, the lender or investor also would need to prove that his *reliance* on the borrower's misrepresentations was *reasonable*.

Your description says nothing about the terms of those "legal contracts", or what [mis-]representations the creator of that cryptocurrency makes to lenders. Absent that information, no reasonable person would grant a loan without assessing the risk of borrower's default. A lender who *bears the risk* despite his very *limited knowledge* of the matter (see [Restatement (Second) of Contracts](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/p/restatement-second-contracts.html) at § 154(b)) is unlikely to prove the element of *reasonable reliance*.

The [notion](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/59037/creating-my-own-crypto#comment121430_59037) that "*the entire finance system is fraud [...] because the fed prints money*" is a very different matter. Although monetary policy *de facto* typically centers on causing the depreciation of [domestic] fiat currency, the loss of purchase power is too slow to prompt holders of US dollars to switch to a different currency. The prevalence of the US dollar is evidence of that. By contrast, the scenario you outline has no information for a reader to rule out the mental picture that lenders will suddenly notice their money is gone.

Furthermore, the dynamics of entire economies are highly dependent on the trends of the US dollar, something that cannot be said of a new, unknown cryptocurrency.